# vim adding new elements to syntax keywords using color scheme file?

Tags: vim, syntax, fortran, color-scheme

I am trying to modify fortran syntax using a color scheme file.

In color scheme, these functions works fine.

```
hi! link fortranConditional     Function
hi! link fortranRepeat          SpecialChar
hi! link fortranBoolean         SpecialChar
hi! link fortranReadWrite       SpecialChar
hi! link fortranIO              SpecialChar
hi! link fortranConstant        Underlined
```

I want to add more element into different syntax keywords too. But for now, I can only use file type auto command like this:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.f90 syn match fortranType        "[()]"
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.f90 syn match fortranIntrinsic   ":"
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.f90 syn match fortranConstant    "[%,]"
```

Is there any way that I can write `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.f90` only for once? Or is there other way I can add elements in color scheme files? Or the right way to do this is to create a new syntax file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The direct answer to your question for grouping is to create a function and call that function:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.f90 call LoadFortranSyntax()

function! LoadFortranSyntax()
  syn match fortranType        "[()]"
  syn match fortranIntrinsic   ":"
  syn match fortranConstant    "[%,]"
endfunction
```

However the recommended and proper way of adding something to a syntax file, is using your `~/.vim/after/syntax` directory. For example:

**File:** `~/.vim/after/syntax/fortran.vim`

```
syn match fortranType        "[()]"
syn match fortranIntrinsic   ":"
syn match fortranConstant    "[%,]"
```

This is described in the help, under the topic [`mysyntaxfile-add`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#mysyntaxfile-add).

Comment: @user3716774 You're welcome! I'm happy if this helped you :-D